# Unable to parse json data and keep it in grid using dojo

Tags: javascript, json, datagrid, dojo

I got the json object data from servlet as this:

```
{"persondetails":[{"salary":"20000","sname":"XXX","sno":"1"},
{"salary":"50000","sname":"yyy","sno":"2"},
{"salary":"20300","sname":"bbb","sno":"3"},
{"salary":"20100","sname":"chan","sno":"4"},
{"salary":"40100","sname":"lorn","sno":"5"},
{"salary":"10100","sname":"san","sno":"6"},
{"salary":"60100","sname":"sun","sno":"7"},
{"salary":"20200","sname":"chan","sno":"8"},
{"salary":"10200","sname":"san","sno":"9"},
{"salary":"40200","sname":"lorn","sno":"10"}]}
```

Now, I have to put this in datagrid using dojo. I tried but I'm getting a blank page. Please check this and help me understand what I did wrong.

Here's my code:

```
var grid, dataStore, store;
    require([ "dojox/grid/DataGrid", "dojo/store/Memory",
            "dojo/data/ObjectStore", "dojo/request/xhr", "dojo/dom",
            "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/json", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!" ],
            function(DataGrid, Memory, ObjectStore,xhr, dom, domConst, JSON, on) {
                xhr("myserveraddress:7080/GridExample/login", {
                    handleAs : "json"
                }).then(
                        function(data) {


                            domConst.place("<p>response: <code>"
                                    + JSON.stringify(data) + "</code></p>",
                                    "output");

                            store = new Memory({
                                data : data.items
                            });
                            dataStore = new ObjectStore({
                                objectStore : store
                            });

                            grid = new DataGrid({
                                store : dataStore,
                                query : {
                                    id : "*"
                                },
                                structure : [  {
                                    name : "SNO",
                                    field : "sno",
                                    width : "100px"
                                },{
                                    name : "SNAME",
                                    field : "sname",
                                    width : "100px"
                                },{
                                    name : "SALARY",
                                    field : "salary",
                                    width : "200px"
                                } ]
                            }, "grid");
                            grid.placeAt("myGrid");
                            grid.startup();                 

                        }, function(err) {
                            alert("error");
                        }, function(evt) {

                        });
            });
```

Comment: Am I missing something? I don't see any store or layout, so how do you expect this to work?

Comment: @DimitriM   i changed my code plz check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give the grid the array inside persondetails.

So your store should be something like::

```
data.items.persondetails
```

Also in your grid you dont need the query parameter, unless you want a certain row like

```
sno:"9"
```

will only show rows with sno = 9

fiddle::http://jsfiddle.net/theinnkeeper/57pZf/